# S3 AWS SDK Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream on

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am using AWS SDK to upload a file to S3. Locally works fine, but on the deployed server it gives this error: **Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.**

Here is the code:

```
var location = $"some-location";
using (var stream = request.File.OpenReadStream())
{
    var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        Key = location,
        BucketName = configuration["AWS:BucketName"],
        InputStream = stream,
        AutoCloseStream = true,
        ContentType = request.File.ContentType
    };
    var putResponse = await amazonS3.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

    response.IsValid = putResponse.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

request.File is FormFile and passed in from controller like this:

```
public async Task<UploadResponse> Upload(IFormFile formFile)
{
    if (formFile is null || formFile.Length <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formFile));
    }

    //TODO: Validate File Extension

    UploadResponse response;

    UploadCommand command = new UploadCommand();
    command.File = formFile;

    response = await mediator.Send(command);

    return response;
}
```